# Two points of view on constructible sets

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, examples-counterexamples

This question is aimed at understanding the relationship between two different definitions of the *constructible sets* in a Noetherian scheme, both of which I encountered in Atiyah-MacDonald's *Introduction to Commutative Algebra* (henceforth AM). It follows up a [question I asked before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1337968/reconciling-two-different-definitions-of-constructible-sets), which was beautifully answered by user [hot_queen](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/72316/hot-queen).

**The setup:**

Let $X$ be a set and $\{U_\lambda\}_{\lambda\in\Lambda}\subset 2^X$ a family of subsets of $X$ that is closed under finite intersection, so it serves as a base for a topology $\mathscr{T}$.

Let $\mathscr{F}$ be the smallest family of subsets of $X$ that contains $\mathscr{T}$ and is closed under complementation and finite intersection. By exercise 20 of ch. 7 in AM, $\mathscr{F}$ is equivalently the family of finite unions of locally closed sets. AM defines this as the *constructible sets* in exercise 21 of the same chapter.

Meanwhile, let $\mathscr{G}$ be the coarsest topology in which every $U_\lambda$ is clopen. In exercises 27-28 of chapter 3 of AM, it is shown that if $X$ is the Spec of a ring $B$ and the $U_\lambda$'s are the standard basic opens of the Zariski topology, then this is precisely the topology in which the images in $X$ of the Specs of all $B$-algebras are taken as the closed sets. AM defines this as the *constructible topology* in exercise 27. AM notes that the closed sets are exactly the images of Specs, so I infer that it is the closed sets of this topology (i.e. the image in $2^X$ of the family $\mathscr{G}$ under complementation of each member; call it $\mathscr{G}^c$) that AM means to refer to as constructible.

$\mathscr{F}$ is not equal to $\mathscr{G}$ or $\mathscr{G}^c$ in the generality in which I've defined them. In fact $\mathscr{G}$ depends on the base $\{U_\lambda\}$ chosen for $\mathscr{T}$ whereas $\mathscr{F}$ only depends on $\mathscr{T}$. See hot_queen's answer to my question linked above for beautiful simple examples of the differences. (I framed that question in terms of $\mathscr{F}$ vs. $\mathscr{G}$, since I forgot the context in AM ch. 3 of the def. of $\mathscr{G}$, but the examples show the same for $\mathscr{G}^c$ because $\mathscr{F}$ is invariant under complementation.)

I assume, however, since AM is using the same word for them, that *if* $X$ is the Spec of a noetherian ring, $\mathscr{T}$ is the Zariski topology, and $\{U_\lambda\}$ are the standard basic sets $X_f$ of this topology (i.e. the Specs of the localizations of the underlying ring at single elements), then $\mathscr{F}$ coincides with $\mathscr{G}^c$. So:

**My questions:**

1) Is this true? (I.e. that $\mathscr{F}=\mathscr{G}^c$ if $X$ is the Spec of a Noetherian ring, $\mathscr{T}$ is the Zariski topology, and the $\{U_\lambda\}$'s are the standard Zariski basis opens?)

2) If yes, which if any of these assumptions can be loosened? Does it remain true if we use a different base for the Zariski topology (e.g. the whole topology)? If yes, does it matter what base? If it doesn't, can the statement be loosened to if we just assume $(X,\mathscr{T})$ is a noetherian space (rather than the Spec of a noetherian ring)? And what are the proofs and/or counterexamples?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, $\mathscr{F}$ and $\mathscr{G}^c$ are usually very different.  For instance, suppose $X$ is irreducible, Noetherian, and $1$-dimensional, so that it has a generic point $g\in X$ and a nonempty set $U\subseteq X$ is Zariski-open iff it contains $g$ and is cofinite.  Then $\mathscr{F}$ consists of the sets that either are cofinite and contain $g$ or are finite and do not contain $g$.  But $\mathscr{G}$ contains every singleton other than $\{g\}$, and thus contains all subsets of $X\setminus\{g\}$ since it is closed under arbitrary unions.  So $\mathscr{G}^c$ contains all subsets of $X$ containing $g$ (in fact, it consists of exactly the sets that either contain $g$ or are finite).

What is true is that $\mathscr{F}=\mathscr{G}\cap\mathscr{G}^c$.  That is, the constructible sets are the *clopen* sets in the constructible topology.  In fact, this is true for Spec of any ring as long as you change the definition of $\mathscr{F}$ slightly: $\mathscr{F}$ should be the smallest collection of sets containing the basic Zariski-open sets $U_\lambda$ and closed under finite Boolean operations (in the non-Noetherian case, this is different from your $\mathscr{F}$ since not every Zariski-open set can be obtained as a *finite* union of basic open sets).

With this definition, let us prove that $\mathscr{F}=\mathscr{G}\cap\mathscr{G}^c$ always holds.  Clearly $\mathscr{F}\subseteq\mathscr{G}\cap\mathscr{G}^c$.  To prove the reverse inclusion, we will first show that the $\mathscr{G}$-topology is compact.  To show this, suppose you have a collection of sets, each of which is either basic open or closed with respect to the Zariski topology, and these sets have the finite intersection property; we wish to show their intersection is nonempty.  Let $\{U_i\}$ be the basic open sets in your family and $\{C_j\}$ be the closed sets; we may assume each of these collections is closed under finite intersections.  Note that any basic open set is compact in the Zariski topology (since it is Spec of a localization of the ring), and so $U_i\cap \bigcap C_j$ is still nonempty for each $i$.  Thus writing $C=\bigcap C_j$, the family $\{U_i\}\cup\{C\}$ still has the finite intersection property.  But now $C$ is a closed subset of $X$ and thus is Spec of some ring $A$, and the sets $U_i\cap C$ are the sets of prime ideals of $A$ that do not contain $f_i$, for some elements $f_i\in A$.  The finite intersection property of these sets says that for any finite collection of the $f_i$, the multiplicatively closed set they generate does not contain $0$.  It follows that the multiplicatively closed set that all the $f_i$ generate does not contain $0$.  Thus localizing at this multiplicatively closed set, we get a nonzero ring, and any prime ideal in this ring gives a point of $C\cap\bigcap U_i$.

Now suppose $C\subseteq X$ is clopen for the $\mathscr{G}$-topology.  Since $C$ is open, we can write it as a union of sets from $\mathscr{F}$.  Since the $\mathscr{G}$-topology is compact and $C$ is closed, $C$ is compact, so actually only finitely many of our sets from $\mathscr{F}$ are needed to cover $C$.  Since $\mathscr{F}$ is closed under finite unions, $C\in\mathscr{F}$.

A similar argument can be shown to work more generally whenever you have a topological space $X$ which is sober and such that the compact open subsets of $X$ are closed under finite intersections and form a basis for the topology of $X$ (in particular, this applies to any Noetherian sober space, since any subset of a Noetherian space is compact).  Letting $\mathscr{F}$ denote the collection of sets generated by the compact open subsets of $X$ under finite Boolean operations and $\mathscr{G}$ denote the topology generated by $\mathscr{F}$, we can then prove that the clopen sets for the topology $\mathscr{G}$ are exactly the elements of $\mathscr{F}$.  (Sobriety of $X$ is used in place of the ring-theoretic argument I gave above that $C\cap\bigcap U_i$ is nonempty.)

In fact, however, this result is not actually more general, because the spaces $X$ satisfying the hypotheses above (called *spectral spaces*) are exactly the spaces that are homeomorphic to Spec of a ring.  This is a fairly difficult theorem of Hochster; see [this paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1969-142-00/S0002-9947-1969-0251026-X/) for a proof and much more on the general theory of spectral spaces (the topology $\mathscr{G}$ is what Hochster calls the *patch topology*).